# In ASP.NET MVC4, how to redirect to {controller}/{id}?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing, authorize-attribute

I have the following route configuration in a ASP.NET MVC4 project:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name:        "HttpError",
  url:         "{controller}/{id}",
  defaults:    new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" },
  constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Now, I would like to know how can I create a `RedirectResult` or `RedirectToRouteResult` that generate an URL that point to `/Error/403` instead of `/Error/Index/403`.

**Extra information**

I'm trying to redirect *unauthorized* users from a custom implementation of `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` inside of its overridden method: `HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your case:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                                                         {
                                                             {"action", "Index"},
                                                             {"controller", "Error"},
                                                             {"id", "403"},  
                                                         });
}
```

You have to take into account that your route has to be placed in appropriate place - before the more general routes, for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "HttpError",
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
```

If you reverse the order, MVC will fetch the first route that fits, and redirects you for example to  `/Error/Index/403` instead of `/Error/403`.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to Route allows you to do something similar to the following:

```
return RedirectToRoute("HttpError", new { controller = "Error", id = "401" }
```

which should generate a link without an action.

Comment: I don't have the `RedirectToRoute` method. I was clear that I'm inside `AuthorizeAttribute` *not* inside a `Controller`. Anyways thanks for your time and dedication. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the filterContext.Result like so (for failed authorisations)

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new  {  Controller = "SomeController", area = "MayBeSomeArea" }));
```

You should do this where -where you are Overriding the HandleUnauthorizedRequest Method of the `AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: Thanks, but at this moment [the answer of @Jaroslaw Waliszko is more complete](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13607762/439427).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this was exactly what you were looking for, but for me, just returning something like this was enough

```
return RedirectToRoute( new {controller = "controller_name", 
                             action = "action_name"});
```

Comment: You're right, instead of redirecting to controller/action, I was looking to redirect to controller/id (without action).

Comment: Also, I can't do that because I don't have the `RedirectToRoute` method, because I'm inside a derived class from `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Oh fair enough, now I see your other comment saying the same thing!